# Connect Hosted-UI cognito with jhipster

Tags: amazon-cognito, jhipster

I am trying to connect the Hosted-UI interface of cognito with jhipster, but I really have no idea how to do it, I generated the jhipster project, I am only generating the front end according to the jhipster guide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC39R.png)

From AWS I customized the login and it works fine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLIT7.png)

I am calling the URL that Cognito provided me from login.service, apparently when I generate only the front end with jhipster the default authentication is JWT I am using this guide; https://blog.ippon.tech/aws-cognito-and-jhipster-for-the-love-of-oauth-2-0/
but it is intended for a monolithic application that is configured with OAuth 2.0, any help is welcome